# How do I create this button in an eclipse plugin

Tags: button, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Inside my eclipse plugin I want to create this button in a composite:

[image]

Where do I get the icon? How do I create that button?

Comment: I can't see the icon.  I think your link is broken.

Comment: Works for me. It's on imgur. Maybe the service was broken...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I found by digging a little deeper...

Create an IAction:

```
private class RemoveCurrentGraphAction extends Action {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateWith(new ModuleGraph());
    }

    public RemoveCurrentGraphAction() {
        setToolTipText("Reset to empty graph");
    }

    @Override
    public int getStyle() {
        return IAction.AS_PUSH_BUTTON;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor() {
        return PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages()
                .getImageDescriptor(org.eclipse.ui.ISharedImages.IMG_ELCL_REMOVE);
    }
}
```

Then when creating the view, add the action to the toolbar:

```
IActionBars bars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
bars.getToolBarManager().add(new RemoveCurrentGraphAction());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import the plugin org.eclipse.ui (Import -> Plug-ins and Fragments) and search the icon. I found an icon very similar (eclipse 4.2) located at icons/full/dlcl16/progress_rem.gif